# How to read all properties of json line by line in powershell code

Tags: powershell

```
isEnabled           : True
isBlocking          : True
isDeleted           : False
settings            : @{scope=System.Object[]}
isEnterpriseManaged : False
_links              : @{self=; policyType=}
revision            : -1
id                  : -1
url                 : https://dev.azure.com/accenturecio01/4f4fc83f-91fb-4a0b-a81c-56113f9559f2/_apis/policy/configurations/-1
type                : @{id=90231074-b810-4521-ac14-ca5aa6781f42; 
                      url=https://dev.azure.com/accenturecio01/4f4fc83f-91fb-4a0b-a81c-56113f9559f2/_apis/policy/types/90231074-b810-4521-ac14-ca5aa6781f42; 
                      displayName=Commit entries restriction}

createdBy           : @{displayName=Ravindra Dacharla; 
                      url=https://spsprodcus1.vssps.visualstudio.com/A5cb9ba94-b73a-4bf8-bf15-d520120bbeb2/_apis/Identities/0900d461-2aea-64aa-8b9a-f0ee02d99f73; 
                      _links=; id=0900d461-2aea-64aa-8b9a-f0ee02d99f73; uniqueName=ravindra.dacharla@accenture.com; 
                      imageUrl=https://dev.azure.com/accenturecio01/_api/_common/identityImage?id=0900d461-2aea-64aa-8b9a-f0ee02d99f73; 
                      descriptor=aad.MDkwMGQ0NjEtMmFlYS03NGFhLThiOWEtZjBlZTAyZDk5Zjcz}
createdDate         : 2022-12-29T04:53:34.5242202Z
isEnabled           : True
isBlocking          : True
isDeleted           : False
settings            : @{minimumApproverCount=2; creatorVoteCounts=False; allowDownvotes=False; resetOnSourcePush=False; requireVoteOnLastIteration=False; 
                      resetRejectionsOnSourcePush=False; blockLastPusherVote=False; scope=System.Object[]}
isEnterpriseManaged : False
_links              : @{self=; policyType=}
revision            : 1
id                  : 5756
url                 : https://dev.azure.com/accenturecio01/4f4fc83f-91fb-4a0b-a81c-56113f9559f2/_apis/policy/configurations/5756
type                : @{id=fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd; 
                      url=https://dev.azure.com/accenturecio01/4f4fc83f-91fb-4a0b-a81c-56113f9559f2/_apis/policy/types/fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd; 
                      displayName=Minimum number of reviewers}
```

this is my json output i want to fetch the value of minimumApproverCount=2 only when type: displayname = Minimum number of reviewers.

Comment: But this is not json?

Comment: Pipe to `Where-Object`.  e.g. $jsonOutput | Where-Object {$_.Type.displayName -eq 'Minimum number of reviewers'} | Select-Object -Property @{n='minimumApproverCount';e={$_.settings.minimumApproverCount}}

Comment: You need to select the property similar to what OP did in following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75107198/show-output-with-earliest-logon-time#comment132545881_75107198